# How to change submit button text without function loss?

Tags: ajax, drupal-7, form-submit, ajaxform

I have big ajax form with 4 dropdown fields and add/romove buttons beneath each of them. The problem is that I can't make form work if button values are the same, and I need them to be the same at least visually because it looks ridiculous otherwise. If they have the same #value it is the last button which gets called every time. So new dropdown fields are added to 4-th "dropdown region". It would be perfect if there were #title or #text for #submit type field. But there is none.

This is example of one of the buttons I'm writing about. Doesn't matter if callback or #submit are different for every button. If the value is the same(including if it's done be translation module), last one is called.

```html
    if ($form_state['num_names_3'] > 1) {
      $form['dropdown_fieldset']['remove_name_3'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Remove one 3'),
        '#submit' => array('order_wood_3_add_more_remove_one'),
        '#ajax' => array(
          'callback' => 'order_wood_3_add_more_callback',
          'wrapper' => 'dropdown_fieldset',
        ),
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please apply `#name` property in your fields then only your custom define submit works no matter if `#value` text is same or different.

```
if ($form_state['num_names_3'] > 1) {
  $form['dropdown_fieldset']['remove_name_3'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Remove'),
    '#name' => 'remove_name_3',
    '#submit' => array('order_wood_3_add_more_remove_one'),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'order_wood_3_add_more_callback',
      'wrapper' => 'dropdown_fieldset',
    ),
  );
}
```

It may be helpful for you.

Thanks,